# Does require in javascript/nodejs executes same file everytime it is imported in another modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, es6-modules, javascript-import

Does `require()` in JavaScript/Node.js executes the same file every time it is imported into other modules?

If yes, how can I have one array in one file and append/update values in it from another JS file?
For example, I have an Array in one file and I am updating the Array from multiple files and I want all of them to interact with only the updated array. How can I achieve this?

Comment: `require()` only runs the file once, then uses the cached export. Not sure what the rest of your question is asking, or if it still applies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Modules are cached, if you load them again cached copy is loaded.

https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_cache

> Modules are cached in this object when they are required. By deleting
> a key value from this object, the next require will reload the module.
> This does not apply to native addons, for which reloading will result
> in an error.
>
> Adding or replacing entries is also possible. This cache is checked
> before native modules and if a name matching a native module is added
> to the cache, no require call is going to receive the native module
> anymore. Use with care!

You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/clear-module

```
const clearModule = require('clear-module');
const myArray = clearModule('./myArray'); // but you need load this everytime to get fresh copy of that array
```

Instead, you can expose a function from your module to read the array value, so it will fetch a new value always.

### myArray.js

```
const myArray = [1];

const get = () => {
  return myArray;
};

const update = (data) => {
  myArray.push(data);
};

exports.get = get;
exports.update = update;
```

### index.js

```
const myArray = require('./myArray');

console.log(myArray.get()); // [1]
console.log(myArray.update(2)); // update the value
console.log(myArray.get()); // [1,2]
```

So now use `myArray.get()` always to read the value and use `myArray.update(data)` to update the.